# rails Redirect to action incorrect URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scenario being:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

So as to avoid nesting more than 2 levels deep I have re-factored this to be:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :articles
end
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

My article show action URL is:
/magazines/3/articles/11

In this view I have a form for creating a new comment.

When a comment is saved successfully the form redirects which all works well.

When the form submission is not successful I wish to redisplay the view with validations errors displayed. I understand the correct way to do this is to render the 'articles/show' view. This also works and the view is redisplayed with the validation errors shown.

The problem is when the save fails and articles/show is rendered the URL is no longer correct and is shown as:
/articles/11/comments

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article  = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @article.comments.order(created_at: :asc).page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
    @comment  = Comment.new
  end
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @article.comments.new(discussion_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'articles/show'
    end
  end

  private

    def discussion_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing my routes back to the way it originally was and now the article show action includes the magazine in the url.

I understand this breaks the "no more than 2 levels deep" routing rule but it's the only way I can get it to work.